# Make new responses appear as a row at the top of  a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I made a web form based off of a Google spreadsheet. New responses currently manifest as new rows on the bottom of the spreadsheet. There is a "Timestamp" column marking the time of submission.

How do I make newer rows appear at the top?

Comment: You sort it by the timestamp column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply suggest that you use the Timestamp column to sort the rows from new to old (Z-A).